# Smartfox server - session were removed when i go for a zone monitor option

Tags: smartfoxserver

i get this issue for the basic examples given in the SFS,
in the another scenario when i am trying to login the admin its again creating a new session and working fine with zone configuration alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Session` object represents a connected client in the system. Normally a `Session` is not able to interact with the server until a `Login` operation is successfully executed. Once this is done the `Session` is promoted as `User` and the interaction is allowed. You can only see `Users` in `ZoneMonitor`